# How can I profile an ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to improve the performance of an ASP.NET MVC app.  Pages take about 700 msec to display, and I know that my controller takes about 200 msec.  This means the View is taking 500 msec.  How can I profile a View?

I don't know regular ASP.NET -- perhaps there are standard things everyone else is aware of?

My View iterates over my Model and displays a table of about 25 rows.  I'm surprised it takes 500 msec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default view engine ( the web forms view engine ), you may be able to use the standard asp.net tracing to see what is happening in the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I was looking for.  I thought ASP.NET had something like that, but I was searching for "profiling" and not "tracing".